# Is there a web browser for iOS that will allow me to change the user agent?

Tags: ios, applications, web-browser

I am using iOS 5 on an iPad and I'd like to be able to change the user agent. Is there a web browser that allows me to do this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A list of iOS browsers which allow user agent switching:

- [iCab Mobile](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/icab-mobile-web-browser/id308111628) ($1.99)
- [Sleipnir Mobile](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/sleipnir-mobile-web-browser/id404732112) (Free)
- [Web Captain](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/web-captain/id1296674405) ($2.99)
- [Lunascape](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/lunascape-web-browser/id380065805) (Free)

Comment: Was there a reason you made that CW?

Comment: Yes, I wanted it to potentially be a comprehensive list and this leaves it open to additions I was unaware of.

Comment: Update since june 2022: Sleipnir got an update with a bug on the user agent feature.

Answer (score 1):

There are many apps that have this functionality, but my personal favorite is [iCab Mobile](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/icab-mobile-web-browser/id308111628).

Comment: (See the community wiki answer above for a move comprehensive list.)

Answer (score 0):

Mercury Browser, which is about 99 cents on the App Store

Comment: App taken off App Store

Answer (score 0):

You can do this on Apple Safari browser on iOS/iPadOS by navigating to

Settings -> Safari -> and then select Request Desktop Website -> All websites

This will present a 'Mac' Safari user-agent.

Comment: Some sites like chase.com are still able to see that I’m on mobile. Any ideas on how to fix it?